# Merge multiple documents to a single PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, birt

I have a requirement in which I have to merge multiple documents (Tiff, DOC, PDF,PNG,JPEG) in to a single PDF file. Any idea how do I do this merging using java (suggest APIs, jars, framework to be used).

Comment: Maybe my project can help you, It open source. Please take a look on [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j2p/?source=directory).

Comment: Do you have jsf and birt as tags because you are currently using them?

Answer (score 2):

You can create PDFs in Java using either XSL-FO or iText.  The former is an XML transform solution; the latter is an in-memory Java library.

You can read Word docs using POI (I've had no luck with it - awful stuff) or docx4j.

You're on your own with the rest.  Maybe someone else will know more than me.

Comment: +1 for iText. 

You can create PDFs with XSL-FO, but it's not particularly suited to the task at hand here.